# How can I subtract all elements of an array from all elements in another in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

I need to subtract a number from an array x1 from all the numbers in an array x2 and check if the absolute value of the result is less than 0.01, if it is then append x1 to a new array. I then need this to repeat for all the elements in the array x1.

Doing this is going to require 25 billion calculations as both arrays are long (50000 and 500000 elements), so I'd prefer to minimize the amount of processing required.

Thank you!

```
b = np.zeros(len(a), 1)               #a is a list of numbers 48555 elements long
b[:,0] = a[:,0]

e = np.zeros(len(d), 1)               #d is a list of numbers 531261 elements long
e[:,0] = d[:,0]

h = np.zeros(len(len(a)*len(d),1)     #h needs to be an array of length a*d
for i in e, j in b,
if abs(i-j)<=0.01,
h.append(i)

print h
```

I haven't used code much before so I'm still making fairly basic errors with Python.

Comment: So not a1 - b1, a2 - b2 but a1 - b1, a1 - b2, a2 - b1, a2 - b2? The number of calculations suggest the second but maybe you mean the first?

Comment: That definitely sounds like something you could do with some code. Good luck! What is your question?

Comment: Is it your assgnment? Give us what u tried

Comment: Do you need to do these operations or are you just interested in the "new array"?

Comment: @RedX it's the second. It's to check if two sets of coordinates, each set from a different instrument have a possibility of being the same, so if the difference between the coordinates is less than the error in the instrument then they could be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
x1 = np.array([5, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6])
x2 = np.array([ 0, 6, 3, 4, 2, 7])

print all(abs(np.subtract(x2 ,x1[1]) < .01))
True

print all(abs(np.subtract(x2 ,x1[0]) < .01))
False
```

You can loop over x1 and continue as soon as any value is > .01 to avoid checking all values:

```
for ele in x1:
    if any(abs(x - ele) > .01 for x in x2 ):
        continue
    else: add your array
```